# What is the equivalent toassertAlmostEqual() from Python in Junit?

Tags: kotlin, junit, assertion

I am programming an application in Kotlin that converts radians to degrees and vise-versa. I was testing it with JUnit and received this error.

```
// The code I ran
assertEquals(60.0, radians.toDegrees())

// The stacktrace
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
Expected :60.0
Actual   :59.99999999999999
```

There is nothing I can do about this, as the program was dividing by PI and then multiplying by PI later on. I was wondering if there was a way I could run a comparison that would count this as a success because the values are close enough. In Python, you can use `assertAlmostEqual()` with a couple of parameters. What is the equivalent of doing this with JUnit.

I am using JDK 11, Java 8, Kotlin 1.3(whatever the latest version is)

Comment: There should be an overload of `assertEquals` accepting 3 doubles, the last one being the delta: `assertEquals​(double expected, double actual, double delta)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [JUnit 4](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertEquals(double,%20double,%20double)) and [JUnit 5](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.1/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html#assertEquals-double-double-double-) you can specify a delta in the method when comparing doubles, specifying how much variance you are willing to tolerate.

```
assertEquals(60.0, myValue, 0.005);
```

There's also the [Hamcrest IsCloseTo](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/number/IsCloseTo.html) matcher, which sounds more like what you're used to.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I can't believe I've used JUnit this long without knowing this.